# How do I install the Neo4j-spatial plugin?

Tags: neo4j

Vanilla neo4j 2.2.0 install on a Ubuntu 14.04 system via their repository.

The instructions given on the neo4j-spatial website don't work. Does anyone have something that works no-questions-asked?

Is there some binary repository I can just apt-get install neo4j-spatial and not deal with this mess?

Thanks!

```
$ mvn install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Neo4j - Spatial Components
[INFO]    task-segment: [install]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error building POM (may not be this project's POM).


Project ID: org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.2

Reason: Error getting POM for 'org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.2' from the repository: Unable to read local copy of metadata: Cannot read metadata from '/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.2/2.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata-oss.sonatype.org.xml': end tag name </body> must match start tag name <hr> from line 5 (position: TEXT seen ...</center>\r\n</body>... @6:8) 
 org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.2:pom:2.2-SNAPSHOT


 for project org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.2
```

Answer (score 0):

The Neo4j-Spatial Project was updated and released for Neo4j 2.2

The readme was also updated with the new binary download links.